# Policy for picture-only indentify-this-movie questions

Tags: discussion, identify

This is my first day on this site, so I'm asking here to make sure I've understood the rules. Basically, I want to know what's your policy towards picture-only indentify-this-movie questions.

[My question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65182/from-which-movie-is-this-photo-taken) has currently received -3 votes (which really frustrates me, as a new user), but I found on this site many positively-voted indentify-this-movie questions which merely contain a picture without providing extra information (which frustrates me further). Here are some examples: [example1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/what-movie-is-this-from?rq=1), [example2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/who-is-this-actor-and-from-what-movie-is-he), [example3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16852/who-is-this-actor), to name just a few.

Why is it? What does my question lack?

BTW: If you really think my question worth downvoting, please at least leave a comment to explain the reason.

Comment: Please don't let this discourage you from participating here.  Unfortunately, those types of questions are off-topic for this site.  I agree that you should have not been flooded with downvotes or at least have received some feedback on why.  Try exploring the site some more and I am sure that you will love it like I do :)

Comment: Unfortunately, not many people comment when downvoting for fear of reprisal (aka "Serial Downvoting").  Image only questions tend to get downvoted, *especially* when the image is a link to a sketchy site.  At that point, it's feared that the post is SPAM and/or the link leads to a virus-infected site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The examples you have provided are 2-3 years old. The site policy for Identification questions has been changed since then.

With a huge numbers of bad questions accumulating on the main site, a stricter policy was introduced.

What an identification question should contain is mentioned [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Detailed ID questions makes it easy to identify a movie/TV show/actor.

In order to identify a movie/TV Show/actor provided with a picture, you can see [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10644/27264).

You can try to give as much details as possible when identifying something from picture, such as where and when did you find it, source(if available), etc.

Comment: What if the only evidence I have is that picture? I've searched around, but found nothing helpful...

Comment: Of course, you have found that picture from somewhere; you didn't create one. Therefore, you can also mention the source, which will also helpful.

Comment: Wont matter. Picture only questions are still off-topic even if you link to its source.